# Calling function in response to network code

Tags: c#

I was wondering, how can I avoid a giant switch statement when trying to handle code received from a network source? The message comes in with an opcode (int), with the function to be called depending on aforementioned opcode (not my design, and I can't influence it).

I need to call a function in response to the opcode, but I don't necessarily want to have to hard-code the opcode to function mapping using a switch statement, because that would make it rigid and hard to fix if the network schema changes.

tldr how can I tie an int to a function - noting that the functions may be distributed across the entire solution (each message may require different state information/may belong to a different class) Right now I have marked functions with attributes, but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary` to map the int to a handler:

```
var handlers=new Dictionary<int,Action<NetworkData>>();
handlers[Opcode.Foo]=HandleFoo;
handlers[Opcode.Bar]=HandleBar;

void HandleFoo(NetworkData data)
{
  // Whatever
}

void HandleBar(NetworkData data)
{
  // Whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your functions have the same signature `MyFunctionDelegate` you can use a `Dictionary<int, MyFunctionDelegate>` which maps ints to the methods.

If the opcodes range from 0 to N with no gap you can also use a simple array or list.

Answer (score 0):

There are definately a few different ways to handle it... However, as usually, the hard-code will actually provide the FASTEST output.

But, if you can handle a little extra latency (and I definately mean a little...) you could try a `Dictionary<int, TMessage>`.

I would recommend that the type `TMessage` have a method that would be able to read it's self in.  Meaning the code would first read the "op code", use it to pick out the `TMessage`, and then have the message read the rest in.

If you wanted to get fancy... you could use `reflection` to populate the dictionary, so you don't have to hardcode ANYTHING.

Comment: Reflection being the attribute usage :P This is basically what I use now.

Comment: Then you wouldn't need a hardcode at all!  As you add messages, `reflection` will be able to add them to the `Dictionary`.